# 2011 Dodge Caravan having problems starting

Tags: dodge, caravan

Last year, I had the same problem when it got cold.  It was the fuel pump relay, so I bypassed it.  We had severe cold again this week, and I am having the same problem.  However, the fuel pump relay is already bypassed.  I checked the fuses on the bypass and they are fine.  I can hear the fuel pump turn on, as a matter of fact, it does not turn off until I take the key out and open the car door.  The car gets stuck in the turn over position, so the starter appears to be working.  I got a new battery already.  Not sure what else to check.  Maybe I need to get a new bypass.

Comment: This is a "cranks, won't start" situation?

Comment: How about spark? How about fuel pressure and injector pulse? Any codes in the engine computer? What engine do you have?